# What is a practical usage of refs in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to understand  why there are refs in React,  and what problems they can 
 help me to solve. In my opinion, React documentation is not great with explaining why i would need to use refs, and i could not find any good articles either.  According to the  documentation, there are a few good use cases for refs :

> Managing focus, text selection, or media playback. Triggering
>   imperative animations.  Integrating with third-party DOM libraries.

However, i can't figure out any practical usage for it.

Also, this example is taken from [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/working-with-refs-in-react/#article-header-id-4) :

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.username = React.createRef();
    this.password = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      errors: []
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const username = this.username.current.value;
    const password = this.password.current.value;
    const errors = this.handleValidation(username, password);

    if (errors.length > 0) {
      this.setState({ errors });
      return;
    }
    // submit data
  };

  handleValidation = (username, password) => {
    const errors = [];
    if (username.length === 0) {
      errors.push("Username cannot be empty");
    }

    if (password.length < 6) {
      errors.push("Password should be at least 6 characters long");
    }

    return errors;
  };

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>React Ref Example</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          {errors.map(error => <p key={error}>{error}</p>)}
          <div>
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input type="text" ref={this.username} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="text" ref={this.password} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <button>Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

They use refs for the form validation, but what is the point ? Is not  it better to use state for this purpose ?  Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score -1):

Refs can help you to retrieve the id,name or change the value of specific element

Comment: It seems to me that i can do it with state , could you elaborate or provide a practical example where i do need to use refs to achieve something ?

Comment: this link will help you alot https://medium.com/@mrewusi/a-gentle-introduction-to-refs-in-react-f407101a5ea6